# Is there a way to print following pattern in C? Note that there are no spaces in between

Tags: c

[image: The character in the image is asterisk]

**Is it possible to print this pattern as is without spaces in between the asterisks?**

Comment: Depends on your output device and, in case of a terminal, the terminal capabilities. (also it's irrelevant whether this is using C or not) You could for example use some graphics library to draw the pattern, or in case of terminal, you could use full-width asterisks that span two columns if the terminal supports it (`＊`), or possibly use the eight spoked asterisks character (`✳`)

Comment: I want to print it on screen.

Comment: Not easily because it requires a half-spaces.

Comment: That still doesn't answer my question unfortunately... I mean, assuming you run outside of an OS, you could just poke it into video memory in graphics mode or in case of text mode define custom characters with asterisk halves but I guess that's not the answer you need, so you have to be a bit more specific ^^

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but probably not to a terminal/console. With spaces, that would be a cinch. Without spaces you are probably looking at opening a graphics window, selecting a font, etc.

Comment: Use [Thin space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_space) Unicode character?

Comment: I meant printing to a terminal/console using standard library of c.

Comment: The standard C library doesn't know about consoles or graphics windows.

Comment: this question should not get down votes, this is not just a simple homework problem.

Comment: @please_don't_hurt.....what is it?

Comment: @MartinJames: check the answer by MichaelBurr and compare it with the answer by shreydeshwal. later one is the homework problem solution.

Comment: @prafulhy If you want to print on screen, you need to specify what OS you're using. Do you want this for Windows?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili I am using Ubuntu.. Also I think Michael Burr’s answer justifies everything.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't really a C problem, it's a target device problem.  If you're writing to a graphics device then you can certainly draw the design.  If you're dealing with a character device then it becomes a matter of what fonts/character sets might be supported.  For example, many devices will allow you to specify a custom character set using bitmaps or maybe a custom monospaced TrueType/OpenType font.

In order for me to illustrate what I'm talking about, pretend that '<' represents the left half of an asterisk, '>' represents the right half and that one character on the custom device is represented by 2 characters here.

Design 4 custom bitmap characters:

1. a full asterisk: `'<>'`
2. a left-half asterisk: `' <'`  ("abutting" the right side of the character cell)
3. a right-half asterisk: `'> '` (abutting the left edge of the character cell)
4. a right-half/left-half: `'><'`

In the following diagram there are "device" 5 character columns.  Those 5 columns are represented here by 2 characters each with '|' characters  separating the device columns to make the columns easier to visualize (they would not appear or take space on the device's display).  Now your image would be created like so:

```
| 1| 2| 3| 4| 5|  column numbers
+--+--+--+--+--|
|<>|<>|<>|<>|<>|  a row of 5 "normal" asterisk characters
| <|><|><|><|> |  a row of 4 made up of various "half-asterisk" characters
|  |<>|<>|<>|  |  a row of 3 normal asterisks
|  | <|><|> |  |  2 asterisks made up of half-asterisks characters
|  |  |<>|  |  |  1 normal asterisk
+--+--+--+--+--+
```

Without the '|' characters to help visualize the columns, this display would look like:

```
<><><><><>  a row of "normal" asterisk characters
 <><><><>   a row of various "half-asterisk" characters
  <><><>    a row of normal asterisks
   <><>     half-asterisks
    <>      a normal asterisk
```

This technique would be similar to drawing a diagram using one of the character sets that contains "box drawing" characters: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character